# Unable to get Autowired to work or do a component scan

Tags: java, spring, maven, inversion-of-control, autowired

I'm using Spring for the first time and even though I feel like I'm familiar with the core IoC concept, I'm having trouble getting the @Autowired configuration working.  I've created this github to demonstrate (stack: basic service using Jersey/Tomcat/Spring/Maven):

https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example

I'm not using any sort of xml configuration (either for Spring or Tomcat).  I can start the server and map to my Jersey end point successfully using `mvn clean tomcat7:run` but my service is hitting a NullPointerException because the object I'm trying to Autowire isn't being initialized by the Spring framework.

Here is the break down of my current makeup:

- [Class with object I'm trying to autowire](https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example/blob/master/src/main/java/dkwestbr/spring/autowired/example/WebEndpoint.java)
- [My configuration](https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example/blob/master/src/main/java/dkwestbr/spring/autowired/example/config/AppConfig.java)
- [Where my config is being loaded](https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example/blob/master/src/main/java/dkwestbr/spring/autowired/example/Initializer.java)
- [My component/bean declaration](https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example/blob/master/src/main/java/dkwestbr/spring/autowired/example/stringGetter/impl/A.java)

**Why isn't spring detecting/initializing my autowired variable?**  I've been reading through tutorials for a while now and am at my wits end.  It doesn't help that most tutorials are written using xml configurations.

---

Below are the specific code snippets which I'm referencing above:

The class with the variable I'm trying to initialize via the `@Autowired` annotation:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class WebEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private IStringGetter getTheThing;

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getStuff() {
        System.out.println(getTheThing.getItGood());
        return String.format("<html><body>Hello - %s</body></html>", getTheThing.getItGood());
    }
}
```

My config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.**"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    private static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties")
    static class Production { }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("test")
    @PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties")
    static class Test { }
}
```

Where the config is being loaded:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

        Map<String, String> filterParameters = new HashMap<>();

        // set filter parameters
        filterParameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example");
        filterParameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath", "/WEB-INF/app");
        filterParameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex", "/(images|css|jsp)/.*");

        // register filter
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterDispatcher = context.addFilter("webFilter", new ServletContainer());
        filterDispatcher.setInitParameters(filterParameters);
        filterDispatcher.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
    }

}
```

The `@Configuration`/`Bean` definition that I'm hoping would map to the `@Autowired` variable:

```
@Component
public class A implements IStringGetter {

    @Bean
    public IStringGetter getTheThing() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItGood() {
        return "I am an A";
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: I'm providing the stack trace on request (This is line 20: `System.out.println(getTheThing.getItGood());`)....

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.WebEndpoint.getStuff(WebEndpoint.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: We don't want to follow links. Post relevant code and configuration in your question directly.

Comment: Will do.  I assumed that this would be more concise since it involves more than a few code snippets but I'll post some code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - my question has been updated with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a quick look at your classes, it seems to me like you aren't integrating Spring with Jersey. The `ServletContainer` will scan and create its own instance of your `WebEndpoint` class, but it has no knowledge of the Spring context available in the `ServletContext`.

For complete Spring-Jersey integration, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/). You will need to switch to `SpringServlet` and add a new library that binds the two.

---

As for your configuration, the `@Bean` annotation only makes sense in the context of a `@Configuration` annotated class. This doesn't make any sense

```
@Component
public class A implements IStringGetter {    
    @Bean
    public IStringGetter getTheThing() {
        return new A();
    }    
    @Override
    public String getItGood() {
        return "I am an A";
    }    
}
```

Get rid of the `@Bean` method. With a `@ComponentScan`, `@Component` annotated classes will be instantiated and the bean will be added to the context. Also changed your `AppConfig` `@ComponentScan` to

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example"})
```

It recurs through that package.

Your two nested `@Configuration` classes also serve no purpose as it stands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still having problems.  I switched to the SpringServlet but I'm seeing basically the same thing.  My new code is here (previous code is commented out): https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example/blob/master/src/main/java/dkwestbr/spring/autowired/example/Initializer.java

Comment: Thank you for the further recommendations but still no luck.  I've implemented both of your recommendations (removing bean and changing package scan) and I'm still now seeing anything.  I've updated the github w/what my current code looks like.

Comment: @dave Please post your exception stack trace too.

Comment: @Dave Don't forget to annotate your `WebEndpoint` class with `@Component`.

Comment: That worked - thank you so much for the help!  If only I could upvote you twice.

Comment: @Dave You're welcome. The take-away here is that Spring can only inject Spring managed beans. If Spring isn't the one instantiating your objects, it cannot autowire things.

Answer (score 1):

For beans not managed by Spring use `extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` and it should work.
In the above example make class `WebEndpoint` extend `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`